# How to make widgets stuffed in AppBar.actions not stretch vertically?

Tags: flutter

Please tell me how to make widgets stuffed in AppBar.actions not stretch vertically?

[image]

```
Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: [
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 6, horizontal: 12),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
              color: Colors.transparent,
            ),
            child: Wrap(
              spacing: 4,
              alignment: WrapAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Icon(Icons.fiber_manual_record, size: 14),
                Text('Online'),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

> It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Comment: please provide some code + details so we can better understand

Comment: add your code snippet

Comment: @MohammedAli added

Comment: you want to align the text and dots in center of the container right?

Answer (score 2):

Ran into the same problem. For anyone else that might come across this. You can use a `FittedBox` with `fit: BoxFit.scaleDown`

```dart
AppBar(
  actions: [
    FittedBox(
      fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
      child: Button(),
    ),
  ],
)
```

Comment: You saved my day, thanks! FYI, the default 'fit' value works for me.